# MPDF library causing cache problems on ajax (blob) download

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

For example, when I click download, it is downloading the data from the previous click.

I think blob is causing the problem, but it seems without it, it's not possible to make it work with jQuery.

Here is my php and ajax code which is working okay, but there is server caching I guess.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'native',
  url: printBulkWpApi.url,
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  xhrFields: {
    responseType: 'blob'
  },
  data: {
    ids: data.join(","),
  },
  success: function (data) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    // Add the element to the DOM
    link.setAttribute("type", "hidden"); // make it hidden if needed
    link.download = "single_issues_print" + new Date() + ".pdf";
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
  }
});
```

```
public function print_function_bulk_actions(){
  function print_callback_bulk_actions (WP_REST_Request $request) {

    global $wpdb;

    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../vendor/autoload.php';  

    $filename = "single_issues_print.pdf";

    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0
    header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'");
    ob_clean();
    readfile($filename);


    $ids = $_POST['ids'];
    $ids_array = explode(",", $ids);

    $array = [];
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    foreach($ids_array as $id){
      // echo $id;
      $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orders.id = $id");
      $mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>'.$results[0]->item_title.'</h1>');
      $array[] = $results;
    }
    // var_dump($array);

    $mpdf->Output('single_issues_print.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
  }



  register_rest_route( 'order-center/v1', 'bulk_print/?', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'print_callback_bulk_actions',
  ) );
}
```

Comment: Hello Kjire and welcome to Stack Overflow. What happens if you open the Developer Tools (F12 in your browser), click the "Network" tab, check that "Disable Cache" is enabled and then test the download? If you are not running into the caching issue, this means it's a client-side problem. If that's the case, use `url: printBulkWpApi.url + '?' + (new Date()).getTime(),` to prevent client-side caching.

Comment: Hello @SaschaM78 and thank you for writing. I've found my mistake and it was in my js code.

link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data) was creating an url which is not the same as the one on the root where the pdf is being saved.

Comment: Good to hear you were able to fix it. Would you mind writing a short answer to your own question and mark it as a solutin (which will be possible after a waiting time of I think about 2 days). Otherwise people might still try to find a solution for your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my java script code. 
`link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data)` was creating an object url which is not the same as the pdf file generated on my root.
I've changed `link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data)` to `link.href = domain.name/pdf_file_name` and the problem was solved.